# Open a file in a new tab

Tags: javascript, c#, html, blazor

How can I open a file(pdf or image) in a new tab in BLAZOR?

I tried using:

1. `await JSRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("open", new object[2] { path, "_blank" });`
2. `using a javascript function with window.open();`

In  Both cases I got: This localhost page can’t be found. What should I do?

Comment: Where does the file come from?

Comment: If you have the path directly from the filesystem, you could either transform your file in base64 and display a blob url on window open. Or if your file is in the same server as your localhost you can use relative path in terms of your localhost server.

Comment: Yes, it s a file from my filesystem

Answer (score 0):

Check proper extension of the image or URL path is correct.

You can follow the below example:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('img.image').click(function(){

        window.open($(this)[0].src, '_blank')

    });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Two options I can suggest:

1. Via a button.

```or-tag-here
@inject IJSRuntime jsRuntime

<button @onclick="@LoadPage">Load Page</button>

@code {
    async Task LoadPage()
    {
        await jsRuntime.InvokeAsync<object>("open", "MyPage", "_blank");
    }
}
```

2. Via a link.

```or-tag-here
<a class="dropdown-item" href="MyPage" target="_blank">
```

where the razor page you want to launch has the following at the top:

```or-tag-here
@page "/MyPage"
```

Answer (score -1):

If you would like to open a tab you can use this.

HTML:

```
<a href=".pdf" target="_blank"></a>
```

**You will  need to fill in the href for where you want to go.**